# QEMU keys not functional

Tags: qemu

I have installed several operatings systems under qumu. Host OS is ubunti 17.10, guest OSes are MS-DOS 6.22, OS/2 warp 4.52, Windows 98 SE.
In all cases, keys on my keyboard are non-functional even though they work in the host. And I also tested the keyboard on real hardware running both Windows 98 SE and OS/2 Warp 4.52 and those keys do work. So, the OSes do support the keys yet qemu is somehow blocking them. The keys that do not function in qemu are:

arrow up
arrow down
arrow left
arrow right
insert
home
page up
page down
end
delete

How do I get these keys functioning in the guest OS under qemu?

Comment: I would at least try as OS that is not at end of life.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665412/mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-in-qemu-emulator

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem, but was able to fix it as follows:

In my case, I had to run a `i386` system with

`qemu-system-i386 -hda tty.qcow2 -boot c`

I modified this with `-k en-us` so now the command is:

`qemu-system-i386 -k en-us -hda tty.qcow2 -boot c`

Now my directional keys function.